# Upload and display 3d Obj file in html

Tags: html, object, iframe, 3d

Im trying to display 3D obj files in HTML.
  But this displays just numeric values instead of interactive 3D Image.

```
<iframe src=“eternalspring/Eternal spring - retopo.obj” width=“800" height=“800”></iframe>
```

My final aim is to upload Obj files and display in iframe the uploaded Obj.

```
<input type='file' accept=".obj">
```

Is there a solution for this ? If yes kindly help me

Comment: please tell us what kind of 3D objects are you trying to display

Comment: With extension .obj files